# Формирование SQL запроса. Группировка по датам. Есть идеи?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос, который нужен для отчета и выгрузки в Excel. Ниже сокращенная версия запроса, для акцента на суть проблемы:

```
select 
       ??? вот тут надо написать что-то вроде CASE WHEN .... 
        from orders as o
             join clients as cl on cl.id = o.client_id
             join positions as pos on o.id = pos.order_id
             left join shippings s on pos.shipping_id = s.id

    where o.id = /номер заказа/
      and o.deleted_at is null
      and pos.deleted_at is null
      and s.deleted_at is null
      and cl.deleted_at is null

    group by o.id;
```

Таблица `shippings` содержит в себе поле `out_time`. При группировке хочу вывести колонки с датой и количеством отгрузки по этой дате, что то вроде

```
26-07-2019 | 25-07-2019 | Не отгружено
-------------------------------------
   250     |     38     |     154
```

Есть какие-нибудь интересные методы реализовать это? Хочу сделать все одним запросом, чтобы не нагружать потом в цикле дополнительными запросами и группировкой все это.

Comment: А вы знаете даты, за которые хотите выбирать, или там условно случайные даты?

Comment: Если б знал, было б намного проще ))) Даты могут быть разные

Comment: у вас получается динамическое количество столбцов. Мне не известен какой либо способ сделать такое в обычном sql. Однако если вы все равно это выводите где то, где будет пост обработка, возможно вам просто выбрать это в несколько столбцов и доработать на уровне вывода отчета?

Comment: Да, из за сжатых сроков к такому способу сейчас и прибегаю, клею из двух запросов один массив. Просто думал, что получится в один запрос все запихнуть, а какого-то способа и не знаю

Comment: в 1 запрос можно. у вас будет 3 колонки `id, dt, count` и группировка по `o.id, dt`. Просто уже для отчета эти данные придется чуть чуть развернуть

Comment: Надо посмотреть что из этого выйдет. Попробую

Comment: У MySQL трудности с PIVOT. Но решаемо - хранимая процедура и динамический SQL.

Comment: @Akina, процедуру уже создал. Буду модернизировать. Спасибо !